# Show that $\frac{1}{1+x}H(\frac{x}{1+x})=\sum^\infty_{k=0}[\Delta^kh_0]x^k$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, summation

For a sequence $\{h_n\}_{\geq 0}$, let $H(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}h_nx^n$.  Show that:

$$\frac{1}{1+x}H(\frac{x}{1+x})=\sum^\infty_{k=0}[\Delta^kh_0]x^k$$

What I did was that by proving the $$\Delta^k h_o=\sum^k_{j=0}(-1)^{k-j}{k \choose j}h_j$$

But no clue how to continue.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{1}{1+x} H \left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n \frac{x^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_n x^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m\binom{n+m}{m}x^m \\
  &=& \sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty  h_n x^{n+m} (-1)^m\binom{n+m}{m} \delta_{r, n+m} \\
  &=& \sum_{r=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{r} h_n x^{r} (-1)^{r-n} \binom{r}{n} \\
  &=& \sum_{r=0}^\infty x^r \sum_{n=0}^{r} h_n  (-1)^{r-n} \binom{r}{n} = \sum_{r=0}^\infty x^r \left( \Delta^r h_0 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where we used $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x^m \binom{n+m}{m}$

Comment: Could you explain what the $\delta_{r, n+m}$ means? and also the steps you take to get the triple sum and then back to the double sum?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: $\delta_{i,j}=1$ if $i=j$ and is $0$ otherwise. (That part was easy; I’ll have to look at the rest.)

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: $$\sum_{n\ge 0}h_nx^n\sum_{m\ge 0}(-1)^m\binom{n+m}mx^m=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}h_nx^{n+m}(-1)^m\binom{n+m}m\;.$$ Now multiply this by $\delta_{r,n+m}$, which gives you the double sum when $r=n+m$ and $0$ otherwise, and sum over $r\ge 0$; for each $r$ you get only finitely many non-zero terms, those in which $n+m=r$. Now for each fixed $r$ and $n$ and each non-zero term for that $r$ and $n$ you have $m=r-n$, so $(-1)^m=(-1)^{r-n}$, and of course $\binom{n+m}m=\binom{r}n$ and $x^{n+m}=x^r$. I’d have done it without the triple sum; see the next comment.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Make a change of index in the double sum by setting $r=n+m$. Then the double sum can be rewritten as $$\sum_{r\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge 0}^n h_nx^r(-1)^{r-n}\binom{r}{r-n}\;,$$ and of course $\binom{r}{r-n}=\binom{r}n$.

Comment: Awesome, I am seeing that this really just a change in variables. But I don't understand your limits on that second sum. Do you mean $n \geq 0$ to $r$? And the limits on the second sum are the only ones in which I am confused about. How do you know there are only finitely many? Once you know this how do you determine the upper limit?

Comment: Mr. CodeKingPlusPLus I think I know who you are lmao

Comment: Likewise Mr. computer.nerd

Comment: If my guess is right one's jason and one's tom, right?

Answer (score 0):

What we seek to show here is that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} h_k
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1+z} H\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right)$$
where $$H(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} h_q z^q.$$

The RHS is given by the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{1+z} H\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right) \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+2}}
\frac{z}{1+z} H\left(\frac{z}{1+z}\right) \; dz.$$

Now put $$\frac{z}{1+z} = u \quad\text{so that}\quad
z = \frac{u}{1-u}$$
and $$dz = \frac{1}{1-u} - \frac{u}{(1-u)^2} (-1) \; du
= \frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \; du.$$

We get for the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|u|=\epsilon} \frac{(1-u)^{n+2}}{u^{n+2}}
\times u \times H\left(u\right) \; \frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \; du
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|u|=\epsilon} \frac{(1-u)^{n}}{u^{n+1}}
\times H\left(u\right) \; du.$$

This is $$[u^n] H(u) (1-u)^n$$
which evaluates to
$$\sum_{k=0}^n h_k {n\choose n-k} (-1)^{n-k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} h_k$$
by inspection.